# Redeploying a Google Container Controller when the repository Image Changes

Tags: kubernetes

Is there any way for me to replicate the behavior I get on cloud.docker where a service can be redeployed either manually with the latest image or automatically when the repository image is updated?

Right now I'm doing something like this manually in a shell script with my controller and service files:

```
kubectl delete -f ./ticketing-controller.yaml || true
kubectl delete -f ./ticketing-service.yaml || true
kubectl create -f ./ticketing-controller.yaml
kubectl create -f ./ticketing-service.yaml
```

Even that seems a bit heavy handed, but works fine. I'm really missing the autoredeploy feature I have on  cloud.docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the controller yaml file itself won't delete the actual controller in kubernetes unless you have a special configuration to do so.  If you have more than 1 instance running, deleting the controller probably isn't what you would want because it would delete all the instances of your running application.  What you really want to do is perform a rolling update of your application that incrementally replaces containers running the old image with containers running the new one.

You can do this manually by:

1. For a `Deployment` controller update the yaml file image and execute `kubectl apply`.
2. For a `ReplicationController` update the yaml file and execute `kubectl rollingupdate`.  See: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/rolling-updates/
3. With v1.3 you will be able to use `kubectl set image`

Alternatively you could use a PaaS to automatically push the image when it is updated in the repo.  Here is an incomplete list of a few Paas options:

- Red Hat OpenShift
- Spinnaker
- Deis Workflow

Comment: I was in fact blowing away, both the service and the controller.

The rolling update seems like the way to go for production.  I'm just dealing with staging/test servers so I don't care about outages.  I could also use cloud.docker to push to the google compute engine, but I am supposed to be coming up with a pure container engine solution.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Kubernetes documentation](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/managing-deployments/#updating-your-application-without-a-service-outage):

> Let’s say you were running version 1.7.9 of nginx:
>
> ```
> $ kubectl run my-nginx --image=nginx:1.7.9 --replicas=3
> deployment "my-nginx" created
> ```
>
> To update to version 1.9.1, simply change
>   `.spec.template.spec.containers[0].image` from `nginx:1.7.9` to
>   `nginx:1.9.1`, with the kubectl commands.
>
> ```
> $ kubectl edit deployment/my-nginx
> ```
>
> That’s it! The Deployment will declaratively update the deployed nginx
>   application progressively behind the scene. It ensures that only a
>   certain number of old replicas may be down while they are being
>   updated, and only a certain number of new replicas may be created
>   above the desired number of pods.

Comment: It's a bit different since I am using a replication controller.  But I was still hoping to get an automatic redeploy when the docker registry is touched.  Oh, well perhaps there is some value add service that will do this for me :).